# Google Play Store rejects app even though my app asks the user to be the default SMS app

Tags: android

My app requests the user for being the default SMS app in the very beginning.
Then the app proceeds to ask other permissions like location, storage, camera and record audio. I also request for SMS and MMS permissions but those do not come up.

Google has been rejecting the app with the following response.

> Your app does not prompt users runtime permissions for
>   SMS permissions.

My question is why does android not prompt for SMS permissions even though i request for it?

**1. Does it mean its automatically approved the moment you click ok to your app being the default SMS app.** 
**2. If it does, why is google complaining about it?**

Comment: You need to ask for the permission SMS at runtime. See https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: Check your manifest file. If SMS related permission is there remove them. And then try again.

Comment: @the_dani I am doing those. As i said, i am also asking for SMS permissions but it does not come up. All these are run time permissions.

Comment: @Al-Amin My app aims at being the default SMS app. How can i remove the SMS related permissions?

Comment: Can you post the code, you're using to request the permissions?